# Does Tony the Tiger pronounce 'Grrreat!' as /grrreɪt/ or /gəə.reɪt/?

Tags: pronunciation

Does Tony the Tiger pronounce 'Grrreat!' as /grrreɪt/  or /gəə.reɪt/?
I want to know what you think about his pronunciation in the commercial?

(1) /grrreɪt/ where the liquid becomes syllabic

(2) /gəə.reɪt/ where the epenthetic schwas are used

Comment: Where ? [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LHS4xhzaZs&t=1m0s) or [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxtboWNmsUk&t=0m28s)

Comment: I quite like your question, but mplungjan is right, an audio clip is pretty essential.

Answer (score 3):

It's pronounced ***"grrreɪt"*** - because he's a tiger and the initial grrrr represents a growl.

You can see the growl spelled out in this [picture](http://cartoonician.com/hes-grrrrreat-the-thurl-ravenscroft-interview/) from an article about the voice of Tony the Tiger, Thurl Ravenscroft:

[image]

. . . and a commercial with the famous roar: http://youtu.be/Y_7WgXAlLFg